# WinSCP .NET assembly: Where to define proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am able to define the proxy server by using the WinSCP GUI. If I do this I am able to connect to a remote host. But in code I don't find a way to declare the proxy server for WinSCP.

In this case I receive

> Remote server returned an error (407) Proxy authentication required.

My code:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
   {
       Protocol = protocol,
       HostName = hostname,
       UserName = user,
       Password = pass,
       PortNumber = portnumber
   };

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.ExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe";
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    TransferOptions options = new TransferOptions();
    options.FileMask = mask;


    SynchronizationResult synchronizationResult;
    synchronizationResult =
        session.SynchronizeDirectories(mode, local, path, deletefiles, options: options);

    synchronizationResult.Check();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`SessionOptions.AddRawSettings`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_addrawsettings) to configure raw session settings appropriate for your kind of proxy.

For example:

```csharp
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "3");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "proxy");
```

See a full list of [raw sessions settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings).

---

Though a way easier is to [configure the proxy](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_proxy) in WinSCP GUI and have it [generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.

Comment: Thanks Martin, for this answer and for all you have done with WinSCP.